# New column with mutate and ifelse but keep NAs in R

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse, dplyr

I have a simple question but it is giving me a hard time.

I wish to recode a varibale with a ifelse function but I want to keep the NAs (in the variable "party") as NAs.

This is what I am doing. I have a variable with vote choice ("party") and I want to recode a new variable ("RRP") if participants choose a specific set of parties:

```
df<- df %>%
  mutate(RRP = if_else(party %in% c("4",#SPP/UDC
                                    "12",#Swiss Democrats
                                    "13",#FDU
                                    "14", #PSL
                                    "15"), 1, 0))
```

The problem is that participants who have NAs in the "party" variable are now being recoded as 0 because they don't fullfil the condition in ifelse.

I also tried this:

```
df<- df %>%
  mutate(RRP = if_else(party %in% c("4",#SPP/UDC
                                    "12",#Swiss Democrats
                                    "13",#FDU
                                    "14", #PSL
                                    "15"), 1, 0,  na.rm=TRUE))
```

but it just yield an error.

Do you have any other ideas?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%in%` returns `FALSE` for `NA` value and not `NA`. So when use it in `ifelse`/`if_else` it executes the `FALSE` condition in them. We can use `case_when` here :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(RRP = case_when(party %in% c(4, 12:15) ~ 1, 
                         is.na(party) ~ NA_real_, 
                          TRUE ~ 0))
#  party RRP
#1    13   1
#2    14   1
#3    15   1
#4    16   0
#5    17   0
#6    NA  NA
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(party = c(13:17, NA))
```